# Objective-c: How to recieve thumbnails from a GDATA Url?

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api, gdata

Firstly I have this gdata url which fetched a gdata feed:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/tge2BfiIXiE?v=2&alt=jsonc
```

This is the code to fetch the information from the url:

```
NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/tge2BfiIXiE?v=2&alt=jsonc"];

NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:feedURL];

NSError *error = nil;

NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

NSDictionary *data1 = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"data"];    
NSString *t  = [data1 objectForKey:@"title"];
NSLog(@"Title:%@", t);

NSDictionary *thumbs = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"thumbnail"]; 

NSURL *standardThumb  = [thumbs objectForKey:@"sqDefault"];
NSURL *hdThumb  = [thumbs objectForKey:@"hqDefault"];
```

The code above fetches the title of the video. However the code does not successfully fetch the thumbnails from the gdata url. And when I attempt to `NSLOG` the `hdThumb` url I only receive a `null` response so my question is how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSDictionary *thumbs = [[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
```

Or you can use this syntax to access dictionary values:

```
NSDictionary *thumbs = dataDictionary[@"data"][@"thumbnail"];
```

your problem was that you just forgot to access the "data" dictionary first